# NASM x86 using of nonexisting segment register 7

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm currently writing a simple program in x86 assembly that gets the data at an arbitrary memory address and prints it to the terminal in hexadecimal. It's being assembled in NASM 2.12.02 and I'm running the resulting bin with bochs 2.6.8. I've written a routine called `print_hex.asm` that uses `db` to define an index of ascii characters, as seen below.

`ascii_table: db "0123456789ABCDEF"`

When assembling the full program and running the result, the same line

`(an increasing number)i[CPU0  ] MOV_EwSw: using of nonexisting segment register 7`

prints out over an over again to terminal preceded by a number that keeps increasing. What's strange is if I change the line to

`ascii_table: db "0123456789ABC"`

by simply omitting the last three letters of the string, it works just fine (although the assembled program gets a runtime error when it tries to convert hex values of D, E or F)

What's going on here? Am I not allowed to declare so much data in a row? Is NASM bugging out on me?

Edit: See below for full source code. Note that it is still a work in progress and might have logic errors elsewhere.

```
print_hex:                        ; prints the value stored at bx in hex
    pusha                         ; push all the local registers to the stack
    ascii_table:                  ; define a table to store ascii characters for conversion
        db "0123456789ABCDEF"
    mov ah, 0x0e                  ; move 0x0e to the high byte of ax in preparation for a teletype interrupt
    mov al, "0"                   ; move the ascii char 0 to the lower byte of ax
    int 0x10                      ; perform a teletype interrupt
    mov al, "x"                   ; move the ascii char x to the lower byte of ax
    int 0x10                      ; perfrom a teletype interrupt
    mov dx, 0                     ; move 0 to dx in preparation for the loop
    mov cx, 0                     ; zero out cx
    hex_print_loop_start:
        mov cl, bl                ; move bl to cl to isolate the lowest nybble of bx
        add cl, ascii_table       ; set the table offset with cx
        mov al, cl                ; get the value at the offset index of the table and store it in al for printing
        int 0x10                  ; perform a teletype interrupt
        inc dx                    ; increment dx by one
        shr bx, 1                 ; shift bx right in preparation for reading the next character
        cmp dx, byte 0x04         ; check if the loop has been performed 4 times
        jl hex_print_loop_start   ; if it hasn't been performed 4 times, jump to the beginning of the loop
    popa                          ; restore local registers
    ret                           ; return
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [**About**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [**How to Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing the necessary details, including your code, and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: Looks as if your code tries to "run" the string, i.e. the bytes of the string are interpreted as code, at runtime. Could you post the code of print_hex? Just edit your question and include it.

Comment: Move `ascii_table` **after** the function. Data is code.

Comment: You could have debugged this yourself by using bochs' built-in debugger to single-step through your code, showing you the disassembly.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make better use of the debugger from now on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must move the string data outside the code, because the CPU, after executing `pusha` instruction will execute the string as instructions. Your string is interpreted as the following code:

```
'01'  30 31  XOR BYTE PTR [BX+DI],DH
'23'  32 33  XOR DH,BYTE PTR [BP+DI]
'45'  34 35  XOR AL,35H
'67'  36:37  SS:AAA                   ;  Superfluous prefix
'89'  38 39  CMP BYTE PTR [BX+DI],BH
'A'   41     INC CX
'B'   42     INC DX
'C'   43     INC BX
'D'   44     INC SP
'E'   45     INC BP
'F'   46     INC SI
```

As long as these instructions are pretty random, so random behavior is expected. Notice also, that the stack pointer is modified, so on the exit of the procedure more chaos is expected.

Comment: This worked. I moved the problematic line to after the `ret` instruction and it ran perfectly. For future reference, I should never place anything defined as data in the middle of anything defined as instructions, correct?

Comment: @qaxf6auux - Except if you want to execute  the data as an instructions. Assembly language is the most powerful language ever and such approach can work sometimes for some purpose. You simply need to always know what you are doing. Also, for example in FASM libraries there are macros that allow you to define data anywhere, but later group all defined  data in one contiguous block at separate place.

Comment: @qaxf6auux: It's even better to put read-only data in a separate section, so all your read-only data is grouped together.  Then you don't have to worry about mixing it with your code or jumping over those bytes.  If you're writing a user-space program, you'd use `section .rodata`, or `section .data` for initialized read-only or read-write data, and `section .bss` for zero-initialized space.

Comment: @PeterCordes - it looks like DOS .com file. There is no "separate sections" in the COM files.

Comment: @john: I meant to say "if you were", since I know 16-bit code doesn't usually have a nice OS program loader.  I was guessing boot sector, given the use of bochs, but yeah .COM is possible too.  Of course, the `.rodata` linker section becomes part of the text segment after linking, so everything I said still applies even for making a .COM.  Sections are for grouping things, but for loading (e.g. an ELF binary), the loader only has to care about text/data/bss segments, still not sections like .rodata.  IDK what NASM would do in practice if you use `section .rodata` with `-fbin`

Comment: @PeterCordes From a performance POV, moving certain read only data next to the corresponding code can be better on certain cache architectures, but that's usually not done on x86, though ARM toolchains do that.

Comment: @FUZxxl: heh, half the time time when I try to keep things simple and leave out a detail, someone points it out anyway.  Yes, this is x86 where the only PC-relative addressing mode uses a 32bit displacement (and only available in 64-bit mode), unlike ARM where a nearby literal pool allows loading with an immediate displacement instead of mov low/high to construct an address in a register.  Mixing code and data is actually a performance negative on real x86 HW, because data in an L1I cache line is wasting space, and code in an L1D cache line is wasting space.  (And caches like to prefetch...)

Comment: @PeterCordes Which is why I said “on certain cache architectures.” Maybe I should have said “but not on x86” immediately afterwards.

Comment: Update on this: I noticed this in the NASM manual:  [`7.1.3 Multisection Support for the bin Format`](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html): `Sections may be designated progbits or nobits. Default is progbits (except .bss, which defaults to nobits, of course).` and there are various rules for how sections are laid out into the flat binary output (with start= and ORG, and ordering controlled by follows=).  So yes, you can use sections as a convenience feature when creating flat binaries.  Presumably nothing will zero the bss for you, though.